# Does hierarchical modelling produce the same issues as stepwise modelling?

Tags: multiple-regression, multilevel-analysis, stepwise-regression

I am a bit confused about the differences between these two modelling methods. I previously thought they were the same but some say they are different in their validity.

Can anyone help me to better understand the difference between a stepwise process (usually automated) and a hierarchical process (usually manual)? Does the latter produce the same issue as the former?

Edit: when I think about the hierarchical approach I imagine a similar process to stepwise, where, in order to create an optimal model for data analysis, one add one variable at the time to the model. In the end, one would choose the model that yields the best fit based on different criteria (theoretical rationale, simplicity and low AIC.)

Comment: Can you specify what a "hierarchical" approach would entail?  In your doing so it may become increasingly plain what the difference is.

Comment: @rolando2 I added some more details regarding my idea of the hierarchical approach. I am not sure whether that is the info you were looking for. Happy to add more details if that helps. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I still find your question unclear. Your definition of "hierarchical approach" just reads as stepwise regression to me. What is the difference?